# How can I show text with html format in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, json, regex, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I work on webservice with json and i get text with html format. I want my text have hyperlinks and some other properties where i find from html tags (etc. bold).

I try binding my html string in WebView source but WebView is every time blank. I use this code

```
var browser = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HTMLWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = MyItem.Article;
browser.Source = htmlSource;
```

MyItem.Article string is like this

[image: json sample]

I want something like this inside Label where is inside ListView os something like that.

[image: text with hyperlinks]

How can I do this?

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://javatechig.com/xamarin/xamarin-android-webview-tutorial), does it help?

Comment: i using xamarin forms (ios and android) this is only for android

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should work for you

```
string htmlText = MyItem.Article.ToString().Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
var browser = new WebView ();
var html = new HtmlWebViewSource {
  Html = htmlText
};
browser.Source = html;
```

Because `Xamarin.Forms.HtmlWebViewSource.HTML` expect a pure HTML. Using this you can create a Xamarin.Forms user control with the help of this article http://blog.falafel.com/creating-reusable-xaml-user-controls-xamarin-forms/ Cheers..!

Answer (score 11):

In XAML you can do something like this:

```
<WebView>
   <WebView.Source>
      <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding HtmlText}"/>
   </WebView.Source>
</WebView>
```

You may also need to provide Height and Width of the `WebView` if it's not inside a `Grid`.

Comment: I believe this is the first example I've seen of adding WebView declarations to XAML - after reading some of the documentation for Xamarin.Forms at Microsoft Docs. Certainly helpful

Answer (score 3):

FYI, I've just added the ability to my [Forms9Patch library](http://forms9patch.com) to create labels and buttons where you can format the text via HTML.  For example:

```
new Forms9Patch.Label { HtmlText =  "plain <b><i>Bold+Italic</i></b> plain"}
```

... would give you a label where the text has been formatted bold italic in the middle of the string.

Also, as an aside, it allows you to use custom fonts that are embedded resources in your PCL project without any platform specific work.  And, you can use these fonts via the HTLM `<font>` tag or and HTML `font-family` attribute.

Here are some screen shots from the [demo app](https://github.com/baskren/Forms9PatchDemo):

[image: HtmlLabelDroid1]
[image: HtmlLabelApple3]

Comment: why not if it is a solution

Comment: Forms9Patch is no longer a commercial product.  It is now MIT License open source and does not require a license.  That being said, I still agree with Nick's sentiment.

Comment: @baskren where do I find the MIT licensed source? since all I can find is commercial

Comment: github: https://github.com/baskren/Forms9Patch;  bitbucket:  https://bitbucket.org/baskren/forms9patch2;   Note that the documentation is a work in progress.

Comment: This looks really helpful. The initial walkthrough documentation for VS on Windows and OS X provides a great introduction https://baskren.github.io/Forms9Patch/guides/ It could certainly be of use with e.g HTML content published in RSS syndication streams. Surprised if Xamarin has not yet noticed this project, for bundling with the Xamarin.Forms VS support. Perhaps the original Xamarin.Forms VS project templates could be patched, to make it even easier to get started with

Answer (score 1):

```html
<pre>
    <WebView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
         <WebView.Source>
              <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding HtmlText}"/>
         </WebView.Source>
    </WebView>
</pre>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.