# Interpret HTML tags in a string and edit the text in the string accordingly

Tags: c#, html, xamarin

I am developing a Xamarin app and I have the below text in a string. I am trying to find a way in C# to display this text in a Label and have the text in the title Bold (or underlined if the HTML tag is u or italic if i).

```
<b>What is Lorem Ipsum?</b>

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.      
Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 
1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
make a type specimen book.

<b>Where does it come from?</b>

Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has    
roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 
2000 years old.

© help@lipsum.com
```

Comment: Do you use Xamarin Forms or do you target some specific operating system directly?

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33485763/how-can-i-show-text-with-html-format-in-xamarin-forms